# how to cutting character from other specific character in string

Tags: python, antlr

I have in ANTLR an one line define for error character (tab and single quote) in my input of string such as 
CHAR_ERROR : '"' * ['\t] * '"' {raise CharError(self.text)}; 
and my test input is as "hello, my name's Dummy"
I got output " Char error in String: "hello, my name's Dummy"

But the requirement for the output has to be from the beginning of the string to
the error char only, exclusive of the leading double quote. (e.g the output for above example should be: hello, my name')
Would anyone help me out, please ?

Comment: I don't see how that rule can match that input. It should only match something like `"'"` or `''''"` or `"`, i.e. any number of double quotes (including zero), followed by any number of single quotes or tabs, followed by a double quote.

Comment: Thanks for the comment seep2k, my rule means: everything in string (bounding by pair of double quotes) is accepted just exception of tab and single quote ! So that i think it should catch my input as well.

Comment: That's not what the code you posted does: `'"' *` matches zero or more double quotes, `['\t] *` matches zero or more single quotes or tabs and `'"'` matches one double quote. So this rule will definitely not match the input `"hello, my name's Dummy"`.

Comment: Thanks sepp2k, I just modified the rule as follow:
CHAR_ERROR : '"'  ~[\r\n"]* ['\t] ~[\r\n"]* '"' {raise IllegalCharInString(self.text)};
Now, the error can be catch but the output is full string error with notice of error char

Comment: So do you want only the first part of the string up to the `'` to be consumed or do you want to consume all of it, but only include the first part in the error message? And do you want to also get the error when the input does not contain a second `"`?

Comment: Yes, I just want the first part of the string up to the ' only to be my result output.
With the input that not contain a second ", it will be transferred to other error which named UNCLOSEDSTRING.

Comment: I'm asking whether you need the rest to be still part of the match (regardless of the error message). Or in other words I'm asking whether you want `CHAR_ERROR: '"' ~[\r\n]* ['\t] { ... }` or whether the rule should stay as it is, but you simply want to get a substring in the action? And in the latter case: what's the programming language? Python?

Comment: Yes, i am using Python
My previous reply explained what i need with the rule required.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you don't want to change what the rule matches, but only want to display a certain substring of the the match in the error message. So you can just use Python's string functionality:

```
raise CharError(self.text[1:self.text.index("'")+1])
```

Here we're using 1 as the start index to get rid of the `"` and add `+1` to the index of the `'` to include the `'` in the substring.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, sepp2k !
But self.index(" ' ")  did not work in my code ! i do not know why ? maybe i forget to import some package ?
Could you explain more details, please ! how do i know the index of which certain character in string? i mean the length of string input so different, and the specific character can be in any position ?

Comment: @wildcoder Sorry, that was a typo. It should of course have been `self.text.index`.